# RubyMine doesn't see gems from bundle in Docker on Mac OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundler, rubymine

I'm using a Docker image with some specified environmental variables, such as `GEM_HOME` and `BUNDLE_PATH`.

RubyMine connects to the remote Docker SDK just fine, but I can't see gems added by `bundler`, even though `bundler` itself is there. My profiler can't configure the project because of that, so I am forced to start all tasks and servers from the `Terminal`.

[image: Ruby SDK and Gems]

How do I make my `bundle` gems visible?

---

#### UPD

It actually has a deal with custom `bundle` gems path. After it was changed, gems disappeared from `gem list`. RubyMine takes gems from there, so it can't find those gems.

Does anybody know how to make `gem list` with `bundler` custom gems path?

---

#### UPD 2

Even after adding `bundle` gems to `gem list` I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: I have the same issue. I based my docker development environment on https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker and I have multiple projects. Gems are shared between projects (custom BUNDLE_PATH) in order to improve performances (docker volumes slowness on OSX).

Comment: I also have this exact same issue. It seems related to including a `--path` argument with your `bundle install` command but I can't figure out how to resolve this. For example, we use the very reasonable `RUN bundle install --path vendor/bundle` line in our Dockerfile.

Comment: In your `Dockerfile`, are the env variables `GEM_HOME` and `BUNDLE_PATH` set appropriately? If running `gem list` inside the container shows the gems, I think RubyMine now picks them up. Is this still not working for you?

Comment: Do you have the docker working path mounted properly? It sound like you can communicate over the port just fine, but I believe rubymine needs to be able to peer into the filesystem. On vagrant I used to have to mount my drive into the container/virtual machine to allow them to talk both ways.

Comment: Are you using rbenv or something similar?

Comment: Has anyone figured out this issue? I find Rubymine extremely frustrating to setup.

Comment: Am using rbenv and i have the same issue ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also struggled with the same problem.

Managed to fix it by setting this parameters in `~/.zshc` user profile.

You might have different `RUBY_PATH`, feel free to change it.

```
export RUBY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
export PATH="$RUBY_PATH:$PATH"
export RUBY_VERSION=$($RUBY_PATH/ruby -e "puts RUBY_VERSION")
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/$RUBY_VERSION/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
export GEM_PATH="$GEM_HOME/ruby/$RUBY_VERSION"
```

You can also take it from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/baurzhan-konurbayev/791f5a93c4f2135e82f051296b61d59e)